# concatenating columns from multiple unrelated 1-row resultsets (with group by)

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I found this very similar question here and all I would like to do in addition to this is group by date.  There is a date column present in each sub-query.

[concatenating columns from multiple unrelated 1-row resultsets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105375/concatenating-columns-from-multiple-unrelated-1-row-resultsets)

Each sub-query will all contain the exact same range of dates. I have tried putting group by in each sub-query, and in the outer query, but I can't seem to make a row combining each sub-query for each date. I am using this query in Hive, but I believe any ANSI SQL will work here. Don't quote me on that though. My scenario seems to be a minor variation on the answers found in the link I posted, however I can't seem to make it work.

Here is one query posted at the link I attached above:

```
select A, B, C, D 
from ( SELECT SUM(A) as A, SUM(B) as B FROM X ) as U 
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT SUM(C) as C, SUM(D) as D FROM Y ) as V
```

How do I add a GROUP BY to this when each sub-query has a date column?  Or is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: You should show *your* queries.  I'm not quite sure how a SQL Server query is going to relate to Hive.

Comment: I didn't realize SQL Server was mentioned in the linked question.  Query added.

Comment: care to show some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Create your sample table and generate your sample query this way it will be easy to understand more regarding your post. Use this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select u.dte, A, B, C, D 
from (select dte, SUM(A) as A, SUM(B) as B
      from X
      group by dte
     ) u join
     (select dte, SUM(C) as C, SUM(D) as D 
      from Y
      group by dte
     ) v
     on u.dte = v.dte;
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks!